# Extract all phrases from a pandas dataframe based on multiple words in list

Tags: python, pandas, regex, text-extraction

I have a list, L:

L = `['top', 'left', 'behind', 'before', 'right', 'after', 'hand', 'side']`

I have a pandas DataFrame, DF:

| Text |
| --- |
| the objects are both before and after the person |
| the object is behind the person |
| the object in right is next to top left hand side of person |

I would like to extract all words in L from the DF column 'Text' in such a manner:

| Text | Extracted_Value |
| --- | --- |
| the objects are both before and after the person | before_after |
| the object is behind the person | behind |
| the object in right is next to top left hand side of person | right_top left hand side |

For case 1 and 2, my code is working:

```
L = ['top', 'left', 'behind', 'before', 'right', 'after', 'hand', 'side']
pattern = r"(?:^|\s+)(" + "|".join(L) + r")(?:\s+|$)"
df["Extracted_Value "] = (
    df['Text'].str.findall(pattern).str.join("_").replace({"": None})
)
```

For CASE 3, I get `right_top_hand`.

As in the third example, If identified words are contiguous, they are to be picked up as a phrase (one extraction). So in the object in right is next to top left hand side of person, there are two extractions - right and top left hand side. Hence, only these two extractions are separated by an `_`.

I am not sure how to get it to work!

Comment: does there need to be an underscore?

Comment: underscore (or any delimiter) is to separate one extraction from another [since there can be multiple extractions in one example]

Comment: But you extract a single word at a time. Do you want https://regex101.com/r/hYlANH/1? `df['Text'].str.findall(r"(?<!\S)(" + "|".join(L) + r")(?!\S)").str.join("_").replace({"": None})`?

Comment: Not in the third example. In `the object in right is next to top left hand side of person`, I would be extracting word `right` and phrase `top left hand side`. As all words in the phrase is a word present in the list, they would need to be picked up as one extraction

Comment: This works great when each words in list has to be picked up. But sometimes (example 3), if words are together, they should be picked up as one single entity (`top left hand side`) and hence in this case, not separated by `_`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Extracted_Value"] = (
    df.Text.apply(
        lambda x: "|".join(w if w in L else "" for w in x.split()).strip("|")
    )
    .replace(r"\|{2,}", "_", regex=True)
    .str.replace("|", " ", regex=False)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                          Text           Extracted_Value
0             the objects are both before and after the person              before_after
1                              the object is behind the person                    behind
2  the object in right is next to top left hand side of person  right_top left hand side
```

---

EDIT: Adapting @Wiktor's answer to pandas:

```py
pattern = fr"\b((?:{'|'.join(L)})(?:\s+(?:{'|'.join(L)}))*)\b"

df["Extracted_Value"] = (
    df["Text"].str.extractall(pattern).groupby(level=0).agg("_".join)
)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```py
pattern = fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(L)})(?:\s+(?:{'|'.join(L)}))*\b"
```

The regex will look like

```
\b(?:top|left|behind|before|right|after|hand|side)(?:\s+(?:top|left|behind|before|right|after|hand|side))*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hYlANH/2).

It will match

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:{'|'.join(L)})` - one of the words in `L`
- `(?:\s+(?:{'|'.join(L)}))*` - zero or more repetitions of one or more whitespaces and then a word from the `L` list
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Python demo:

```py
import pandas as pd
L = ['top', 'left', 'behind', 'before', 'right', 'after', 'hand', 'side']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text':["the objects are both before and after the person","the object is behind the person", "the object in right is next to top left hand side of person"]})
pattern = fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(L)})(?:\s+(?:{'|'.join(L)}))*\b"
```

Output:

```py
>>> df['Text'].str.findall(pattern).str.join("_").replace({"": None})
0                before_after
1                      behind
2    right_top left hand side
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, it just compares each items in the list with each item in the the phrase in each row.

```
L = ['top', 'left', 'behind', 'before', 'right', 'after', 'hand', 'side']

df = pd.DataFrame(
['the objects are both before and after the person',
'the object is behind the person',
'the object in right is next to top left hand side of person'], columns=['Text'])

df['Extracted_Value'] = df['Text'].str.split().apply(lambda x: '_'.join([m for m in x if m in L])).replace('',np.nan)
```

My output is,

```
    Text    Extracted_Value
0   the objects are both before and after the person    before_after
1   the object is behind the person                     behind
2   the object in right is next to top left hand s...   right_top_left_hand_side
```

Comment: For (2), the extracted value should be `right_top left hand side`. Word order has to be maintained and also notice `top left hand side` is not separated by `_`

Comment: @Parsh my bad, take a look now, just needed to change the order.

Comment: Why is it not separated ? I am not sure about this, when do you under score and when do you separate?

Comment: As in the third example, If identified words are contiguous, they are to be picked up as a phrase (one extraction). So in `the object in right is next to top left hand side of person`, there are two extractions - `right` and `top left hand side`. Hence, only these two extractions are separated by an `_`